# How do I use a FILE as a parameter for a function in C?

Tags: c, file, function, unix

I am learning C and I come from a Java background. I would appreciate it if I could have some guidance. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "test text\n";
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    write(fp, str);
}

void write(FILE *fp, char *str)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
xxxx.c: In function ‘main’:
xxxx.c:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘write’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/include/unistd.h:363: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
xxxx.c:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘write’
xxxx.c: At top level:
xxxx.c:21: error: conflicting types for ‘write’
/usr/include/unistd.h:363: note: previous declaration of ‘write’ was here
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you're calling the system call [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write). Perhaps include a prototype above `main()` and better still, choose a name not used by a system call while you're at it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your function, the problem is the name choosen ("write" is used in unistd.h) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html

Comment: Thank you all, sorry it's been a long night.

Comment: I think you can also use fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fp). Although the efficiency isn't good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are lacking a function prototype for your function.  Also, `write` is declared in `unistd.h` so that is why you get the first error.  Try renaming that to `my_write` or something.  You really only need the `stdio.h` library too as a side note, unless you plan on using other functions later.  I added error checking for `fopen` as well as `return 0;` which should conclude every main function in C.

Here is what I would do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_write(FILE *fp, char *str)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "test text\n";
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    my_write(fp, str);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See `man 2 write` on linux.

```
#include <unistd.h>

     ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

That is the prototype. You need to pass an integer file descriptor and not a file pointer.
If you want your own function Change the name to `foo_write` or something

Answer (score 0):

There's already a system function called `write`. Just name your function something else, put a function declaration before you use it, and you'll be fine.

Comment: "you'll be fine" -- Wrong. The function must be declared before use.